# Return unexpected set while using max() in MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, sql-order-by

I am in a need of set where STATUS = `Need Corrections` at their last entry.

For the given set:
[image: Table:QC]
I need the 3rd and 5th row, because last entry (i.e) max(entry) of order ORD001 is 2 and max(entry) of order ORD003 is 1 and they has the status 'Need Corrections'.

I tried these queries but getting wrong result.

SELECT * FROM QC WHERE STATUS = 'Need Corrections' AND ENTRY IN(SELECT MAX(ENTRY) FROM QC) GROUP BY PRD_ORDER;
[image: Result when using 'group by']

```
SELECT * FROM QC WHERE STATUS = 'Need Corrections' AND ENTRY IN(SELECT MAX(ENTRY) FROM QC) ORDER BY PRD_ORDER;
```

[image: Result when using 'order by']

Comment: 1. The 2 sample queries are the same. 2. You would get a syntax error not wrong result for the sample query, since `order` is a reserved word.

Comment: your code is failing on many levels.

Comment: *"I tried these queries but getting wrong result."* - The way you have it now, you shouldn't be getting *any* results, but *syntax errors*.

Comment: For example, only I draw this table. In my actual table there is no column in the name of 'ORDER'

Comment: @Shadow If that's their real/actual code, so is `table` ;-)

Comment: *"In my actual table there is no column in the name of 'ORDER'"* - Funny, I see a column bearing the name `ORDER`

Comment: `NEED CORRECTIONS` and `Need Corrections` are two different animals. Sorry, but your question is way too unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think now the revised question is clear enough.

Comment: @PrakashMurugan Thank you. Glad to see you got your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't that far away

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t(id int ,pr_order varchar(10),entry int, status varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values
    -> (1,'o1',1,'NC'),
    -> (2,'o2',1,'NC'),
    -> (3,'o1',2,'NC'),
    -> (4,'o2',2,'F'),
    -> (5,'o3',1,'F');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select t.*
    -> from t t
    -> where t.status = 'NC'
    -> and t.entry = (select max(t1.entry) from t t1 where t1.pr_order = t.pr_order);
+------+----------+-------+--------+
| id   | pr_order | entry | status |
+------+----------+-------+--------+
|    3 | o1       |     2 | NC     |
+------+----------+-------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Exactly this is want Mr. Thank you. :)